# AND and OR function in ArrayFormula

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Can this be turned into an array formula for approx. a thousand cells down the column in my sheet to hopefully reduce processing lag?

```
IF(OR(AND(DAY($Q$42)=DAY(CP22),DAY($Q$42)<>DAY(CP23)),CU21<>""),CQ22,"")
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired otput

Answer (score 2):

change `AND` for `*` and `OR` for `+`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(((DAY(Q42)=DAY(CP23:CP))*(DAY(Q42)<>DAY(CP23:CP)))+(CU23:CU<>""), 
 CQ23:CQ, ))
```